# tcolorbox - how to close gaps for middle lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, addlines

The code below generates a box with blue borders.
I have been attempting to add horizontal dividing lines that have no gaps.

I haven't been successful so far.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you.

[image: current output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{amssymb}     
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=1.0in, bottom=0.8in}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\voffset = 0 cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue,boxrule=1.3mm,colback=white,width=17cm,height=20cm,after=\hfill]
1\quad XXX.\\[0.224cm]
\phantom{XXXX} XXX\\
\verb||\xrfill[1.3mm]{3pt}[blue]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the purpose of `\tcbline` (or `\tcblower`), the style can be set with the `segmentation style` key.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=1.0in, bottom=0.8in}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue,boxrule=1.3mm,colback=white,width=17cm,height=20cm,after=\hfill,
segmentation style={draw=blue,line width=3pt,solid}]
1\quad XXX.\\[0.224cm]
\phantom{XXXX} XXX\\
\tcbline
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked beautifully!